# JPA query for filtering based on property of entity list

Tags: hibernate, jpa, postgresql-9.3, named-query, jpa-2.1

I have a Spring MVC app using Postgre 9.3 and JPA2.1 (Hibernate implementation). I have a Class 'Movie' which has Set of Reviews within it. I want to write a JPA NamedQuery which returns me all the details of Movie but only Approved reviews. Reviews can have other states but I want to display only Approved reviews.

My class looks like the below:

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Movie.findMovieById",
    query="SELECT c FROM Movie c WHERE c.id = :MovieId"),
@NamedQuery(name="Movie.findMovieByIdAndApprovedReviews",
    query="SELECT c FROM Movie c INNER JOIN c.reviews r WHERE c.id = :MovieId AND r.state = 'USER_REVIEW_APPROVED'"),
})
public class Movie implements Serializable {

    //Primary Key
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //Movie Name
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //One Movie can have many reviews hence OneToMany
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="Movie")
    private Set<UserReview> reviews;

    .
    .
    .

}
```

Query which I have written doesn't filter the reviews and return Movie with all the reviews; it works same as findMovieById query shown above.

Is it possible to write such a query? Or do I have to put some other hack for filtering the Approved reviews?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Hibernate filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

```
@FilterDef(name="onlyApproved")
public class Movie implements Serializable {

...

@Filter(name="onlyApproved", condition="state = 'USER_REVIEW_APPROVED'")
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="Movie")
private Set<UserReview> reviews;
```

Then, just activate the filter when performing the query

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.enableFilter("onlyApproved");
entityManager.createNamedQuery(...);
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, I got exception org.hibernate.HibernateException: No such filter configured [onlyApproved] when I tried enabling it in my Movie DAO class. Here is my DAO code:  

 Session session;
         
 session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
 session.enableFilter("onlyApproved");
 
 TypedQuery<Movie> query = em.createNamedQuery("Movie.findMovieByIdAndApprovedReviews", 
   Movie.class);
 query.setParameter("movieId", movieId);

Comment: I forgot to add `@FilterDef` in my answer. You should put it on a class level. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Still it is not working, I don't know where could be the mistake. Do I have to add anything on my UserReview class? I am using my old NamedQuery Movie.findMovieById now since I think Filter would return me the desired results.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but in [this blog post](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/), someone mentions in comments that it works with xml configuration, but not with annotations. Also, could you try with `em.find(Movie.class, id)` instead of named query?

Comment: I could not try with the xml configuration since I using Annotations. I tried with em.find() though but it didn't work for me either. Thanks for giving the suggestion anyhow.